# lightshot for ubuntu 22.04 screen black screen problem

Tags: 22.04

I try to take capture an image and upload to lightshot  it looks like black screen.

ubuntu 22.04 LTS

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the WIne version of it?

Comment: right @n3xtd00rpanda

Comment: is there any solution or any software like this ? @n3xtd00rpanda

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comments on your OP, I would suggest trying to use some other software to see if the issue persists (to ensure it's not an issue with your GFX specifically). I personally haven't had luck with getting Lightshot to work on Ubuntu through WINE. Try something like KSnip (`sudo snap install ksnip`) or gnome-screenshot (`sudo apt install gnome-screenshot`); the latter works on non-GNOME DE's too!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method:
go to your system bios setting by pressing f2 or whatever your system has idk,
then disable "secure boot" from there then try

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue for some other app. May be that can be the reason for this issue also!
By default in Ubuntu, wayland display server is enabled. We need to disable this so that it can use Xorg display server.

to do that, you need to add (or uncomment if it is commented) this line in the GDM3 configuration file (`/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`)

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

After making this change, reboot your system to update this config change.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same situation as you. And here is my solution for this case:

Run the following command:

`sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Uncomment the line

`#WaylandEnable=false`

and save the changes. This will enable the Xorg display manager.

Then either

`sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

Or just reboot the system.

Hope this helps you.